# Display current's hovered object property/name in Unity and C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say I have 5 buttons, each with different names (i.e "red", "blue" etc)
I want to create one function, that when you hover on a button, it changes the "textToDisplay" text propery to the current hovered button name.

Full example :
You have a text which displays "Nothing", but if you hover over button with "red" name, the text will change itself to "red".

I could just create as many functions as there are buttons and match every function with every button seperately, but it's not really a good way isn't it?

TL:DR :
I want to get current's hovered object property.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're currently handling hovering over the buttons?

Comment: To acheive this, I think you may need to derive/extend from the class you're using for your buttons. If I'm not mistaken, there should be an 'OnHover()' type of event to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`IPointerEnterHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerEnterHandler.html) and add this component to the same `GameObject` the `Button` component is attached to.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // passing in "this" as context additionally allows to 
        // click on the log to highlight the object where it came from
        Debug.Log("Currently hovering " + name, this);
    }
}
```

> Ensure an `EventSystem` exists in the Scene to allow pointer detection. For pointer detection on non-UI GameObjects, ensure a `PhysicsRaycaster` is attached to the `Camera`.

---

You than can add e.g. a [`UnityEvent<string>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent_1.html) in order to add callbacks

```
[System.Serializable]
public class StringEvent : UnityEvent<string>
{
}

public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    public StringEvent OnHover;

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // passing in "this" as context additionally allows to 
        // click on the log to highlight the object where it came from
        Debug.Log("Currently hovering " + name, this);
    }
}
```

and than reference callback methods in the Inspector (like with the `onClick`) but note that those methods have to expect a `string` as parameter.

Or in the target component you could add the callback to each of those events like

```
private void Start()
{
    var buttons = FindObjectsOfType<Example>();

    foreach(var button in buttons)
    {
        // it is always save to remove listeners even if
        // they are not there yet
        // this makes sure that they are only added once
        button.OnHover.RemoveListener(OnButtonHovered);
        button.OnHover.AddListener(OnButtonHovered);
    }
}

private void OnButtonHovered(string buttonName)
{
    // do something with the buttonName
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely amazing! Everything works like a charm now, thanks a lot!
Will remember to use this function!